# Can I use 2 fields terminators(like ',' and '.') at a time in hive while creating table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2, hive-serde

I have a file with `id` and `year`. My fields are separated by `,` and `.`. Is there any chance I can in the place of fields terminated by can I use `,` and `.`?

Comment: What kind of delimited file would have 2 separate delimiters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using RegexSerDe.

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE citiesr1 (id int, city_org string, ppl float) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('input.regex'='^(\\d+)\\.(\\S+),(\\d++.\\d++)\\t.*')
LOCATION '/user/it1/hive/serde/regex';
```

In the regex above three regex groups are defined.

```
(\\d+) leading digits is the int id column
dot . is a separator
(\\S+) - string without spaces is the city_org string column
comma , is a separator
(\\d++.\\d++) - float column
\\t - tab separator
```

See details here: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/58591/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-fields-for-hi.html