# Can I get a Json Key into a Hive Column?

Tags: json, hive

I am trying to read data from json files in S3 into my Hive table. If the column names and json keys are same its all loading properly.
 But now I want to read data in such a way that the nested json values goes into specific columns (For eg: for json

```
{"data1": {"key1": "value1"}}
```

I want the `data1.key1` value to go into column named `data1_key1`; which I understand is achievable with `SERDEPROPERTIES`. 
 My next problem is there can be multiple json keys and I want the key names to be column values in my Hive table.

Also, depending upon those keys, the keys that go into other columns will also change.

For eg my json files will be either:

```
{"data1" : {"key1":"value1"}}
```

or

```
{"data2" : { "key2" : "value2"}}
```

This need to create a table as below:

**col1  col2** 
data1  value1 
data2 value2

Is this possible? If so how should it be done?

Comment: Hive does not support dynamic column names. Columns in Hive table should be defined.

Comment: @leftjoin : i agree. we have to first get data1 and data2 in separate columns. Then split the json in these columns into multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using regular expressions. Define json column as string in table DDL and use regexp to parse it. Tested on your data example:

Demo:

```
with your_table as ( --Replace this CTE with your table
select stack(2,
             '{"data1": {"key1": "value1"}}',
             '{"data2" : { "key2" : "value2"}}'
             ) as json
)

select regexp_extract(json,'^\\{ *\\"(\\w+)\\" *:', 1)    as col1, --capturing group 1 in a parenthesis START{spaces"(word)"spaces:
       regexp_extract(json,': *\\"(.+)\\" *\\} *\\}$', 1) as col2 --:spaces"(value characters)"spaces}spaces}END
  from your_table;
```

Result:

```
col1,col2
data1,value1
data2,value2
```

Read the comments in the code please. You can adjust this solution to fit your JSON. This approach allows to extract keys and values from JSON not knowing their names. `json_tuple` and `get_json_object` are not applicable in this case.

Alternatively you can use regexSerDe to do the same in the table DDL like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944328/2700344. For the RegexSerDe solution you need to write more complex single regexp containing one capturing group (in parenthesis) for each column.